# convert linear graph to exponential graph based on the values

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, exponential, exponential-distribution

I want to convert the linear graph to exponential graph.
There are 2 values generated on x-axis value of SCORE which ranges from `[-1,-0.9,-0.8,..0,0.1,0.2,....1]` and y-axis value range from `[0,255]`

The linear graph generated is

[image]

And I want the exponential graph as given in the below image to be generated

[image]

I want to scale the y-values in such a way they have an exponential shape and their maximum value is `255`.

Comment: Do you want to plot both lines or only the exponential scaled one?

Comment: @PabloC Only the exponential scaled

Comment: so in the y-axis you want to plot values from 0 to e²⁵⁵?

Comment: @PabloC I don`t know but just need to convert linear to exponential curve, i am confused how it done

Comment: What do you want the largest value in y to be? 255?

Comment: @Pablo C yes 255

Comment: is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to scale the values for the y-axis, but first you need to do some simple math. As you want your largest y-value to be 255, you need to solve:

[image: eq1]

which results in:

[image: eq2]

So, you have to scale by this number. Now let's see the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,21)
y = np.linspace(0,255,21)

#scaling here
y = (np.e**(np.log(255)/255))**y

plt.xlabel("Score")
plt.ylabel("Pixel")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: according to the score I have pixel values so when I am trying to plot it its not the exponential curve

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Are you trying to fit this plot with an existing curve?

Comment: I got it your answer is correct , I was trying to fit my calculated values.